# how to get related posts with comma separated tagging system for PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, database, web, tags, tagging

I'm creating a website using PHP and MySQL to post related sites. I'm using a tagging system for this site with comma separated tags, for example my tags will look like: **php, mysql, code, programming**.

The reason I use this comma separated tagging system is because **I want the user to be able to insert any kind of tag he wants for his post**.

I have searched from this site and internet, but the answer is not really relevant to my question. Many tagging system use three table like item, tag_map, and tag, and I think it doesn't work for comma separated tagging system.

So far, I have already create a table with name and tag fields in it. The best solution I have found is using **Tf–idf, term frequency–inverse document frequency** to weight the post relative to its content.

Are there any other good solutions for this? If there are not I'm really grateful if someone can explain this tf-idf example using php code.

Comment: so you want a single field in each record to look like `tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,...`? That's bad design. it negates the point of having a relational database to store your information, and makes it a serious pain to do any analysis of tag frequency and/or manipulating tags.

Comment: yeah, i have tried to separate it into post table and tag table, but it will be one-one relation, and i think it's the same.

Comment: there's a reason you find no resources on how to do this - because it's the wrong way.

Comment: *I think it doesn't work for comma separated tagging system* - doesn't work for presentation, or for persistence?

Comment: are there any other good way to implement this? because i want the user can add his own tag for his post. If I use 3 table design, it will make my database really big.

Comment: It will be smaller than your current design, because you won't have lots of duplicate strings in the tags field.

Comment: Although the indexes may negate this space saving, but they'll make up for it in search speed.

Comment: this web is like a blog and the post is unlimited for anything, so the tag also will be unlimited. Is the 3 table design really is the best for this condition?

Comment: @deka yes, 3 table design is best

Comment: How do you think the SO tags are done? They're also unlimited, but they're obvious in a table of their own.

Comment: I think the tf idf is an algorithm to weight the tag or post relative to it's content. You can see it in wiki, I can,t give the link right now. All right then, I will use. The 3 table design. Thx all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the way it shouldn't be done, like the comments adressed. You should split up this in three tables:

A table which stores the posts itself;

```
Table posts
-----------
id
text
```

A table for all the tags;

```
Table tags
-----------
id
name
```

And finally a table to connect the two;

```
Table postTags
-----------
id
postId
tagId
```

When selecting data from these, you can use a query like the one below:

```
SELECT * FROM posts p
INNER JOIN postTags pt ON pt.postId = p.id
INNER JOIN tags t ON pt.tagId = t.id
```